# Сервер на C++ и клиент Java для Android

Tags: java, c++, клиент-сервер

возник вопрос реализации, мне необходимо сделать клиент Android приложение на Java, что бы оно общалось с сервером на windows C++, подскажите как реализовать такое? что почитать где взять информацию? какие сокеты использовать?

Comment: Для windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/winsock/winsock-server-application, для java: https://pro-java.ru/rabota-s-setyu-java/klientskie-sokety-po-protokolu-tcpip-v-java начните с этого.